# detach logo from header menu and put it between header and first part of body

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Dear all geniuses out there,

I'm building a website in wordpress, however I'm not an expert in it.

I'm looking to make logo bigger and put it between the header and the first part of the slider (with same position on the right as now, however way down on the menu so that half part of logo is within the menu and half part within the first part of the slider, making it not affect the height of the header menu)

The website in question is the following: http://www.ildottoredellepiante.it

I'm sure this is possible as I've seen it on few website, does anybody can help me with the answer?

Comment: *the logo should be in the same position as of now --> on the left (not on the right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have something like this in mind?
[Screenshot with modified CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LB1x.jpg)

To achieve this, just add this code to the id `#site-logo` in the `style.css` of your wordpress template:

```
#site-logo {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
}
```

`position: absolute` helps, that the size of the logo container does not affect the height of the header.
`top: 12px` helps to adjust the vertical position of the logo. You can alter that value to change the exact position of the logo.

Comment: YOU ARE A FU****** GENIUS!!!! IF I WOULD HAVE YOU HERE PIZZA AND BEER ON ME ALL DAY!!!! THANK YOU!! ANYTHING I CAN DO TO HELP YOU ON THIS PLATFORM?

Comment: also, last question: how can I adjust the size of it? (make it bigger I mean)

Comment: You can just change the size of the logo itself. The easy way is to set `width=xxx` of the image it self. Best would be to upload the image in the size, which you like to have. Because in the latter way the image quality would be better.

Comment: I'm glad to hear, that my answer has helped you. You could mark it as helpful by clicking on the grey checkmark next to my answer. That would help me a lot :) And welcome to Stack Overflow :)